# Filter to keep only one-to-one matches using data.table

Tags: r, data.table, matching, data-wrangling

I am working with a large table, containing two ID columns. e.g.

```
ID1    ID2
01A    XY1
01B    XY4
...
```

There are duplicate values in both ID columns, and a decision has been made to only keep cases where there is a one-to-one match between the two IDs. i.e. if any of ID1 values match to more than one ID2 value, then all of the rows with that value of ID1 are removed. And vice versa.

I have written some code using `dplyr` that works:

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID1) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(ID2)==1) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  filter(!is.na(ID2)) %>%
  group_by(ID2) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(ID1)==1) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  filter(!is.na(ID1))
```

However, this is quite slow to run due to the size of the table. I am trying to figure out how to do the same thing using `data.table`. I figure it must use some combination of `unique` and `uniqueN`, but can't seem to get it quite right.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: hi does the code work above for your *vice versa* requirement? reason for asking is because, say, ID1=a is mapped to ID2=x,y,z, should you also remove ID1=b if it is mapped to ID2=z? you might need a network approach if you would like to remove b as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do

```
library(data.table)
tmp <- setDT(df)[df[, .I[uniqueN(ID2)== 1], ID1]$V1]
na.omit(unique(tmp[tmp[, .I[uniqueN(ID1) == 1], ID2]$V1]))
```

Comment: Thanks. This method, and the similar one by RonakShah both work well. I like that Ronak's fits on one line, but I accepted this answer as it seems to run quite a bit faster.

Answer (score 1):

In `data.table`, you can do -

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)

na.omit(unique(df[, .SD[uniqueN(ID2) == 1], ID1][, 
            .SD[uniqueN(ID1) == 1], ID2]))
```